# What's the point of const void?

Tags: c++, c, function, constants, void

Apparently, it is possible to declare a function returning `const void`:

```
const void foo()
{
}
```

g++ seems to consider the `const` important, because the following code does not compile:

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same<void(), const void()>::value, "const matters");
```

So does `const void` have any practical significance?

Comment: Without knowing any specifics, I'd say that it's there for orthogonality reasons. Imagine a meta-function that takes the replaces the type, but not the qualifier. It would work with all types, except void if the void could implicitly be stripped away.

Comment: I'm now curious into what led to this discovery. :) Playing with your compiler's intermediate output, are we?

Comment: @Tim: I was trying to decide where to put the `const` in a function pointer lookup table. There were three possible locations. One of them failed to compile, and the outermost `const` clearly declared an array of pointers to functions returning `const void`, and I was surprised the compiler accepted that code.

Comment: cdecl.org is useful for those occasional moments of asking "what does this qualifier apply to?"

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Not really. But to ignore *cv*-qualifications on void or to make them errors could create unnecessary complexity in terms of both compiler implementation and end-user code. Consider templates like

```
  template<typename T>
  const T ...
```

There's no reason to make using void in that scenario a special case (more than it already is), it would just create headaches.

Also, while `const void` isn't helpful, `const void*` has its uses.

Comment: How useful is const void *? I can see how void * const could be, but not the former.

Comment: You can use it to preserve the (intended) const-ness when round tripping through `void*` land. `string read_name(enum dynamic_type, const void*)`. It's not super useful, no, but more so than `const void`. And of course `void* const` is useful but that's not really germane to the question.

Comment: @Spidey If you're already doing stuff like hacking pointers (some `T*`) into `void*` (and back again later), then `const void*` is the `const` equivalent (so for some `const T*`). Sure, you could `const_cast` it away but why? In other words, it's precisely as useful as any other `const T*` and that's "quite a lot". :)

Answer (score 15):

`const void` is allowed simply because there is no point making the compiler kick out this one exception to a general rule and it does no harm to leave it in.

There is some discussion above that `const void*` is not very useful:

> How useful is const void *? I can see how void * const could be, but not the former. –Spidey

In fact `const void*` is sometimes essential.
It declares that the thing being pointed to is read only as opposed to `void* const` which only declares that the pointer itself is constant but not the thing it points to.

From my experience, the pointer to constant using `const void*` is the more useful of the two forms. Of course, there is also `const void* const` meaning that both the pointer and the thing it points to are constant.

`void*` is normally used as a way to pass non-specific pointers around (e.g. with `memcpy()`).
If you want to pass a `const char*` to such a function then you cannot use `void*` or you lose the fact that the thing it points to is constant and cannot be altered. Current C++ compilers will refuse to compile that as it would have to implicitly cast the `const` away, and rightfully so as this data might be in read-only memory and possibly cause an exception if anything tries to write to it.

This is why the second argument to `memcpy()` is `const void*` and not simply `void*`.

Comment: hint: replace single quotes with backticks.