# Different placement of const keyword in method declarations?

Tags: c++, methods, comparison, constants

There some answers for similar questions on stackoverflow, but all of them are incomplete or without comparison (with different examples). I saw at least 3 possible cases of declarations:

1. `const void f();`
2. `void f() const;`
3. `const void f() const;`

What is the difference between them?

The only difference I have found is the following code works with (2) or (3) only:

```
const foobar fb;
fb.foo();
```

Comment: What about `void const f() volatile &&`? Or `volatile void f() & final`?

Comment: Tip: Never declare the return type `const` (as in 1 and 3). It's pointless if there's no return type (as here); mostly harmless but not particularly useful for simple types; but potentially harmful for more complex types since it prevents move semantics.

Comment: sorry, I wrote "void" as example only

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `const` in this position declares the return type as `const`.
2. `const` in this position is only usable for member functions and means the function cannot / won't modify any member non-`mutable` variables (object constness).
3. This is the above 2 combined.

Comment: Wrong.  In 1, the `const` is simply ignored.  And 2 is only a convention.

Comment: I think you'll find the void in the question is simply a filler where the type would be.

Comment: See comment under the question.

Comment: sometimes it is useful, see my answer

Answer (score 6):

A `const` before the method name (as in point 1., and in point 3. of your question) refers to the return type. It means that the result of the function is non-modifiable; but there is a limit to when this const actually makes sense - basically, it usually only makes sense on user-defined types. What it means in the context of a `void` return type though, I have no idea at the moment. My best guess is that it is just ignored by the compiler.

A `const` after the method name (as in point 2. and 3.) makes the whole method const, meaning the method may not modify any members (except such declared `mutable`).

Since your `foobar` variable is declared `const` and thus may not be modified, only `const` methods on it can be called, that's why only 2. and 3. work (they both declare the *method* `const`; in 1. it's only the return type which is const!)

Comment: The return value of a function is an rvalue.  Rvalues of non-const types aren't cv-qualified, so `void const` is the same as simply `void`.

Comment: And what you say for 2 is only a convention (and isn't really the usual convention: the usual convention is that a const function will not modify observable state, nor return anything which will allow modifying it without "breaking" const).

Comment: "And what you say for 2 is only a convention" - what I state is what compilers (more or less) enforce; to me it seems rather what you say is only a convention (compilers can't fully enforce it, but it is of course the thing to strive for) - or else I don't understand what you mean by "only a convention"?

Comment: The only thing the compiler does with a `const` function is change the type of `this`.  A function can still `const_cast` it back to non-const, or obtain a non-const pointer to the object by some other means.  The "convention" is that it won't modify "observable state" (whatever that means in context).

Answer (score 1):

```
1)    const void f();
```

refers to **return type** as constant. Useful in example in templates, where ignoring cv-qualifications on `void` or to make them errors [could create unnecessary complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058021/1141471) in terms of both compiler implementation and end-user code. for example:

```
  template<typename T>
  const T ...
```

The return value of a function is an rvalue. Rvalues of `non-const` types aren't *cv-qualified*, so `void const` is the same as simply `void` - `const` is ignored in this case. While `const void` isn't very helpful, `const void*` however has its uses. g++ confirms that `const void` might matter because the following code does not compile

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same<void(), const void()>::value, "const matters");

2)    void f() const;
```

refers to class **members**. This is function that declares not to change any ( non mutable) member of class/structure nor return anything which will allow modifying it without "breaking" the const. This is why only such function can be called on constant object

```
const foobar fb;
fb.foo();  // OK
```

but

```
void f();
const foobar fb;
fb.foo(); // error
```

finally

```
3)    const void f() const;
```

both above together

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `const` modifies what immediately precedes it (and
should always be written immediately after what it modifies).
In the cases you show:

```
const void f();
```

The const is ignored.  Don't write things like this; it confuses
the reader.

```
void f() const;
```

This declares a "const" function (because the `const` is
immediately preceded by a function declaration.  The notion of
a const function is a bit particular: it only applies to
non-static member functions, and it means that the type of
`this` will be `T const*`, rather than `T*`.  In practice, it is
taken as a promise not to modify the observable state of the
object the function is called on.

```
const void f() const;
```

Exactly the same as the precedent.  The first `const` is
ignored.

There are, of course, many other places `const` can appear:

```
void const* f();
```

for example, declares a function which returns a pointer to
a const void.  (You will often see this written as

```
const void* f();
```

If nothing precedes the `const`, then it applies to what
follows.  As a general rule, however, it is preferable to avoid
this style, even if it is quite widespread.)

Note the difference with respect to what you wrote as the first
example.  Here, the return type is a pointer, and the `const`
applies to what is pointed to, not to the pointer (which would
be `void *const`).  While top level `const` is ignored on
non-class return types (so `void *const f();` is the same as
`void* f();`), this is *not* true for other const.

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where the `const` keyword is used (including the ones you asked about and a few more)

**1. Declared Constants**

> const int constant_variable = 2;

A constant variable's (`constant_variable` in the above example) value cannot be changed after it is assigned with a value.

**2.Constant Member Functions**

> Class Foo {
>        int a_member_func()const;
>        int a_member_variable;
>        mutable int mutable_variable; };

A constant member function is forbidden to change member variables of its object. In this case `a_member_func()` is not allowed to change `a_member_varialbe`, but the especial case is constant member functions can change values of member variables marked as `mutable` (`a_member_func()` can change `mutable_variable`)

**3.Const Reference Parameters and Const Pointer Parameters**

> int a_func(const int& a, const int* b);

In this case `a_func()` is not allowed to change values of `a` and `b`. Constant reference parameters and constant pointer parameters cannot be changed by the function which they are passed to.

**4.Constant Return Type Functions**

> const int a_func();

A constant function (`const` keyword used in front of a function return type), always returns a constant value. This means that `a_func()` returns a constant value.

*This is not a complete list of the uses of the const keyword.*