# It is useful to put a constant destructor?

Tags: c++, constants, destructor

I would want to know if it is useful to put a destructor in constant?
E.g.:

```
class example
{
    public : 

    example(int params); 
    const ~example(); //Here
}
```

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: That is not `c`. Don't mistag your questions

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve with that `const`. Can you explain?

Comment: It is just for knowing if it is possible

Answer (score 2):

From a conceptual standpoint, this does not make any sense. `const` functions have no side-effects. Thus, they need to return something. As the destructor does not return anything, this function would be useless.

(Similar to a [const void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057987/whats-the-point-of-const-void) function by the way)

As noted in the comments, you could still modify `mutable` data in a `const`.

Comment: except in the presence of `mutable` data...

Comment: It is not true that `const` functions have no side effects.   They may produce output (e.g. write to a file, `std::cout`, etc).  They may access global variables and change them.

Comment: Good point - I didn't think of that. Does this make sense to be added to the answer? I feel like my original understanding was not completely correct.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know because I am novice

Answer (score 1):

It's not useful, because it's not possible:

> error: qualifiers are not allowed on destructor declaration

Answer (score 0):

It is not useful, and would typically trigger a warning from the compiler - usually to the effect of the qualifier being ignored.

A `const` qualifier on the return from a function is mostly only useful for functions that return a pointer or reference (e.g. to indicate that the returned reference is to an object that should not logically be changed).   A destructor does not return anything so there is nothing for the `const` to qualify.

Making the destructor itself `const` (i.e.  `~example() const`) will be rejected by the compiler.   That is appropriate since a destructor generally changes state of the object (causes it to no longer logically exist)